# Use a different docname in build tree than in source tree

Tags: python-sphinx

My source tree looks like this:

```
doc/
|- conf.py
|- index.rst
|- foo/
   |- bar/
      |- page01.rst
      |- page02.rst
```

And I'd like a way to automatically rewrite `"foo/bar"` into `"baz"` in document names while sphinx builder processes my documentation source, so that the build looks like this:

```
_build/html
|- index.html
|- baz/
   |- page01.rst
   |- page02.rst
```

I'd like to avoid a dirty workaround based on symlinks, I tried creating a custom extension and playing with the event handlers (`app.connect`) but could not find a way.